# "intermediate" variables in MySQL UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, variables

Couldn't find anything which suits my situation; might be approaching this the wrong way...

How do I create an "intermediate" variable for each line of my UPDATE query? (in the example, the @correction var)

This is mostly for clarity in the query if nothing else.

```
UPDATE `table_with_errors`
JOIN `corrections_table` 
    ON `table_with_errors`.`corrections_table_id` = `corrections_table`.`id`
SET
    @correction = IF(`table_with_errors`.`correction_type` = 1, `corrections_table`.`corr1`, 
        IF(`table_with_errors`.`correction_type` = 2, `corrections_table`.`corr2`, `corrections_table`.`corr3`)),
    `table_with_errors`.`valueA` = `table_with_errors`.`valueA` + @correction,
    `table_with_errors`.`valueB` = `table_with_errors`.`valueB` + @correction,
    `table_with_errors`.`valueC` = `table_with_errors`.`valueC` + @correction;
```

It's pretty ugly already. I'd hate to have to paste in that correction formula in place of every occurrence...
(the real correction query is a bit more nested with user-functions, hence my desire to cache the correction for clarity)

Comment: Instead of a variable, you might approach this as a two step process. Add a column to hold the correction value, and do an update to populate it. Then a 2nd update to apply the correction. You can always remove the column after the process is complete.

Comment: Yes - it's 3am here, and I'm considering to do this, just to finish it - but now I'm also really curious if this can be done :-D

Comment: Oh wait - this won't actually work; there's multiple matches on the join; I'll update the question to be a little more accurate...

Comment: I suppose the extra column could hold the correction which itself is recalculated for each row - in one step instead of two

Comment: It would need to be a two step process since the calculated value wouldn't be "visible" during the 1st step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't find any way to access this 'mechanism' of SQL.
Solved the concrete problem by adding an extra column to hold the correction value first, apply it to the stored data, then delete the column.